# Confused how to draw the asymptotic magnitude Bode plot

Tags: transfer-function, bode-plot

I am trying to solve the following question:
[image]

I have derived the transfer function as follows:

$$H(\omega) = -\frac{2000}{j\omega} - 0.5$$

which I rewrote as the following

$$H(\omega) = -\frac{j\frac{\omega}{2}+1000}{j\omega}$$

What exactly do I do now?

Comment: Multiply the numerator and the denominator by the complex conjugate of the denominator.

Comment: After that how do I graph the asymptotic bode plot?

Comment: Bode plot asymptotes break down 20db per decade at poles and up 20db per decade at zeros.  If there are two poles at the same frequency then 40db per decade.  It would be good to determine where the poles and zeros are.

Comment: I will do that and post my own answer. Could you tell me if it's right or wrong?

Comment: How do I figure out where the plot touches the y-axis?

Comment: Watch the dimensions! What is the dimension of "2000"?

Comment: ok well i managed to model my function $$20\log_{10}|H(\omega)| = 60 - 20\log_{10}(\omega)$$ when $$\omega < 2000$$ and $$20\log_{10}|H(\omega)| = -20\log_{10}(2)$$ when $$\omega  > 2000$$

Comment: Is the above calculation right?

Comment: This is what my comment should have said; Touching the y-axis is a bit of a problem.  This is asking the DC gain.  Since there is no DC feedback this will be the gain of the amplifier.  But is the amplifier is ideal that is infinity.  You can look at limits as the frequency approaches 0Hz or you can figure out the gain at some other frequency far from the poles or zeros and calibrate to that.  Two things that might help you.  Have you considered doing this in the Laplace domain and google the bode plot of an ideal opamp integrator.

Comment: I have to do it without using laplace transforms.

Comment: What happened to 2000 when you put your first equations over common jw denominator?

Comment: I combined the fractions with the common denominator of $$2j\omega$$ and then I divided the numerator and denominator by 2. EDIT: That should be 4000.

Comment: So my function should be
$$H(\omega) = -\frac{j\frac{\omega}{2}+2000}{j\omega}$$

Comment: This moves your zero.  It doesn't change the fact that at high frequencies C1 shorts out the 10KOhm resistor making the gain (1/0.05w)/(1/0.025w)=1/2.  So you can't know where the gain at DC is, but you do at high frequencies.  The pole at 0 tells you there is an asymptote of -20db/decade that goes through the zero.  The the zero add 20db/decade to this making the function 0db/decade past the zero.  The gain of 1/2 at high frequencies tells you the the gain there is -6db.    Would you like to see a simulation of this?

Comment: For the asymptotic plot I drew a straight line from the y-axis with slope -20 until w = 4000 then drew a straight line. And this constant value was -20log(2) (log base 10). Is that right? Obviously at w = 0 the plot isn't defined so I put an open circle, but it's still a straight line with slope of -20. until w = 4000 then it's constant horizontal line.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you've got it.  Here is a simulation schematic;

[image: Schematic for Bode problem]

Here is the result;

[image: Bode Plot]

This is in Hz.  You have to multiply by 2 pi to get w in rad/sec.

Answer (score 0):

Transfer function is: \$\small H(s)=\dfrac{1+sC_1R_1}{sC_2R_1}=\dfrac{1+2.5\times 10^{-4}s}{5\times 10^{-4}s}\$, hence there are three components:

1) \$\small 20log(2000)= 66dB\$

2) -20dB/decade (integrator) passing through \$\omega=0\$

3) 1st order break point at \$\omega=4000 rad s^{-1}\$, with 20dB/decade HF asymptote

If you have to do it without using Laplace transforms, do it using Laplace transform and then replace \$s\$ with \$j\omega\$ in each equation! It's only three or four lines of analysis.

Comment: I don't think those calculations are right. Substituting the values given in the problem I get $$H(s) = \frac{10000+2.5s}{5s}$$

Comment: Yes, got decimal points wrong. Corrected now.